# LoginServlet connecting to Customer Object

Tags: java

I need to know how to add my customer business object Username and password into the servlet so it logs in me

I tried the check user way, but I already have the customer business object
So when I log into the website with the username and password, it'll redirect me to the lookuppage, instead of sending me to the error page

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private String id;
    private String pw;
    private boolean valid;




    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("LoginServlet Running…<br></br>");

            String id = request.getParameter("idtb");
            String pw = request.getParameter("pwtb");
            /*if (id.contains("admin") && pw.equals("123")) {
                out.println("Valid Login");
                RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("accountLookup.jsp");
                rs.forward(request, response);
            } else {
                out.println("Invalid Login<br>");
                RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
                rs.forward(request, response);
            }*/
            if (checkUser(id, pw)) {
                out.println("Valid Login");
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setId("idtb");
                customer.setPassword("pwtb");
                HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("customer",customer);
                RequestDispatcher rs;
                rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("accountLookup.jsp");
                rs.forward(request, response);
            } else {
                out.println("Invalid Login<br>");
                RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
                rs.forward(request, response);
            }
    }
        }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>


    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Looking at the code, the behaviour is for a valid login is  the user is directed to the accountLookup.jsp. If this is not correct, what do you want to happen?

Comment: it's not correct, I don't understand why it's not working